# Canvas Based App Login Not Working With Examples

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I have followed the instructions and setup for both the Friend Smashers example and the Interactive Console example included in the SDK.  I uploaded my builds to a website with SSL and entered all the canvas settings on Facebook.

When I click the login button in either example, no login action is taken.  Within the interactive console, the Status changes to 'Login called', but the UserId, IsLoggedIn, and AccessToken don't change.  The Facebook DLL reports that it was Loaded Successfully and my AppId shows up correctly.

Is there something I am missing in the setup?  I didn't change any code, just used defaults, but neither example works.

Comment: Is the user you're trying to log in with set up as a test user or developer on the facebook app you're using?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same account that created the app.  I don't get a login dialogue at all when I click the login button.  Nothing happens in the UI.

Comment: Hi Mesidin, Can you send me your app id and I'll take a look? you can put it here or email me at unity-sdk@fb.com. Thanks!